# SendMail Powershell - Embedding .html files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to embed HTML tables from .html files (generated externally) into an email using SendMail in Powershell. My code is below:

```
$userid = 'xxx@workdomain.com'

$creds = Get-Credential $userid

$port = 587

$smtp = "smtp.office365.com"

$to = "otherpeople@workdomain.com"

$from = $userid

$subject = "FX summary report" 

$body = Get-Content ("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\R\newtrend.table.html")


$body = $body | out-string
Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body -UseSsl -Port $port -SmtpServer $smtp -From $from -Credential $creds
```

However, this doesn't embed the html code and instead I get the html written as text. My email looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
....
```

I'm not familiar with powershell, and I'd really appreciate a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the parameter `-BodyAsHTML` to your `Send-MailMessage` command. See [`Get-Help Send-MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage).